# Ubuntu queries SNMP devices on system startup

Tags: startup, snmp

Every time I boot Ubuntu - running 18.04 on Virtual box, it hits the SNMP card on every UPS on my network.  I intentionally have SNMP restricted on those devices, but why does Ubuntu feel it necessary to try to login to every one?

And can I make it stop?

I get 4 notices - well over 100 each time I reboot - of these "unauthorized user" attempts for each of the UPSs:

Informational - System: Detected an unauthorized user attempting 
  to access the SNMP interface from 172.16.11.198

Where 172.16.11.198 is the ip of the device running Virtualbox.  Much to the dismay of the other network engineers here, I have tested a few times and it certainly correlates with the Ubuntu reboot.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: `zgrep -i  snmp /var/log/syslog*` will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – I had not looked there.  Unfortunately(?), there is no mention of SNMP or anything that seems even remotely related in the syslog file across the time window from well before the reboot to well after I had received the alerts from the UPSs.  So I guess that tells me that despite what the UPSs are saying, the initiating process is not SNMP related.

I think my next step will be to see what the outbound traffic actually is during a reboot – maybe I will learn something there.

Answer (score 1):

Stop SNMP/UDP autodiscovery broadcast. After disabling SNMP there is still UDP/1124 and UDP/3289 broadcast when booting or plugging in a USB device. I fixed it for me with editing the sane.d conf files:

```
sudo sed -i 's/net autodiscovery/#net autodiscovery/g' /etc/sane.d/magicolor.conf
sudo sed -i 's/net autodiscovery/#net autodiscovery/g' /etc/sane.d/kodakaio.conf
sudo sed -i 's/net autodiscovery/#net autodiscovery/g' /etc/sane.d/epson2.conf
sudo sed -i 's/dell1600n_net/#dell1600n_net/g' /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
sudo sed -i 's/# networking=no/networking=no/g' /etc/sane.d/pixma.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be CUPS scanning for printers to autodetect. Try removing the "cups-browsed" package if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

Configs in `/etc/sane.d/` was a problem for me. `kodakaio.conf` and `magicolor.conf` has an option `net autodiscovery`. Comment it out and no more SNMP requests.

Answer (score -2):

Editing those .conf files in /etc/sand.d/ fixed it for us.  Linux Mint was upsetting our UPS.